# PyQT4 - communication between 2 windows

Tags: python, pyqt4, communication

I've got problem with communication between 2 windows in PyQt.

main window = UI_Form (class MyForm)
additional window = UI_Employee (class Employee)

I'd like, when i clicked AddTextButton (Ui_Employee), to set text in LineTextEdit (UI_Form)
This is my code.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

from Form import Ui_Form
from Window import Ui_Employee

class MyForm(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.AddButton,QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.add)

    def add(self):
        self.Employee = Employee(self)
        self.Employee.show()


class Employee(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self,parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Employee()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ui.AddRowButton,QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self.addText)

    def addText(self):
        self.Form = MyForm()
        self.Form.ui.textEdit.setText('someText')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyForm()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I've got problem with line in method addText. First and second lines are ignored. I dont know why.

Answer (score 3):

In your method `Employee.addText` you create a new `MyForm`. This is probably not what you want. You can access your original `myapp` from inside `Employee` via `self.parentWidget()`.

```
class Employee(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def addText(self):
        self.parentWidget().ui.textEdit.setText('someText')
```